# How to define the path of the new directory with php

Tags: php

Sorry in advance if it is a newbie question, but I am trying to make a file on my desktop with php.

The following script does not work. Any idea what is wrong? I have defined the path (which is my desktop) and the name of the file.

```
<?php

mkdir('/Users/mary/Desktop', "test", 0777, true);
?>
```

Comment: www-data/your_php_user may not have the rights on your desktop. Perform an ls -la and check if your php_user has the rights. And, as habib said, it may also be the absolute path syntax you used.

Comment: Thank you but I tried mkdir('../Users/mary/Desktop', "testeted", 0777, true); still does not create anything on my desktop

Comment: Can you please post the error you are getting? probably a permission issue

Comment: Here is the error PHP Warning:  mkdir() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/makedirectory.php on line 6

Comment: Try this one .       mkdir('/Users/mary/Desktop/test', 0777, true);

Comment: $DiffDirNam='test';     mkdir('/Users/mary/Desktop/'.$DiffDirNam , 0777, true);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try here i mentioned code.
     `mkdir('/Users/mary/Desktop/test', 0777, true);`

Comment: mkdir('/Users/mary/Desktop/test', 0777, true);

Comment: first off, that's not how you post an answer. Second, that's not the right answer.

Comment: that's how you post an answer, but it's still not the right answer. That's exactly what OP put in his question. That will create a directory and CHMOD the directory to 777. Problem is, you can't create a directory in the first place if the parent directory is inaccessable.

Comment: the  question's owner accept this answer. and he wil get solution.

Answer (score 2):

PHP does not have access to write to your desktop. You would need to `chmod` your desktop. Open a terminal and do: `sudo chmod 777 $HOME/Desktop`

That's for Linux/Mac, if you're on Windows it depends on the version.

Comment: chown is better imho since it will give the rights only to the ${php_user}/www-data

Comment: first off, that's not how you post an answer. Second, that's not the right answer.